# How to extract content between two patterns in Unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file `test.txt` containing below code.

```
select * from emp where empid=1;  

select *   
from dep  
where jkdsfj  

select *   
from sal   
where jkdsfj
```

I need to extract the content between "from" and "where".

Note: If "where" is on a new line it must still select the material between "from" and "where".

Output should be like:

```
emp  
dep  
sal
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What if there are inner/outer join in the SQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the need to handle multiple lines, you can choose `sed`, or `awk`, or one of the more complex scripting languages like Perl or Python.

With a bit of care, `sed` is adequate.  I created a file `script.4` (having created `script`, `script2`, and losing most of what little hair was left on my head<sup>**</sup>, and restarting with `script.1`, `script.2` and `script.3`, which were deliberately incomplete) like this:

```
/from.*where/  { s/.*from *//; s/ *where.*//;          p; n; }
/from/,/where/ { s/.*from *//; s/ *where.*//; /^ *$/d; p;    }
```

And I created a test file, `data`, like this:

```
select * from emp where empid=1;  

select *   
from dep  
where jkdsfj  

select *   
from sal   
where jkdsfj  

select elephants
from abject poverty
join flying tigers
where abelone = shellfish;

select mouse
from toolset
join animals where tail = cord
and buttons = legs
```

and ran the command like this, to get the output shown:

```
$ sed -n -f script.4 data
emp
dep  
sal   
abject poverty
join flying tigers
toolset
join animals
$
```

The script is 'simple'.  For lines which contain both `from` and `where`, delete everything up to the `from` (plus any spaces after it), delete everything from the `where` onward (plus any spaces before it), print what's left, and go to the next line of input.

Otherwise, between a line which contains `from` and a line that contains `where`,
delete everything up to the `from` (plus any spaces after it), delete everything from the `where` onward (plus any spaces before it), if the line is empty, delete it; otherwise print it.  Note that adding an `n` command to the second line makes the script misbehave (I need to spend time working out why), but the delete operation can be added to the first command line without doing any harm (if a line contains `from where`, nothing is printed).

Note that there are many SELECT statements that would be mishandled by this code.

For example:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Table1 AS T1
  JOIN (SELECT T2.A, T3.B
          FROM Table2 AS T2
          JOIN Table3 AS T3 ON T2.PK = T3.FK
         WHERE T2.ColumnN > T3.ColumnM
       ) AS T4
    ON T1.A = T4.B
 WHERE T1.DateOfBirth > DATE(2000-01-01)
```

Quite apart from the upper-case keywords, the WHERE in the sub-query would be where the matching between FROM and WHERE stopped.

---

** In case you're curious about the cause of hair loss, look at [Why does an `n` instead of a `b` or `d` or nothing change the behaviour of `sed` in this script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29427151/why-does-an-n-instead-of-b-or-d-or-nothing-change-the-behaviour-of-sed-in-this-s).

Comment: Excellent! I was thinking in some `perl`, but this `sed` seems very complete. I admire your willingness to always provide an excellent answer. Get a +1 in the hope you can exchange it for some hair :)

Comment: Do we need to add this code in separate script                                                      **/from.*where/  { s/.*from *//; s/ *where.*//;          p; n; }**
**/from/,/where/ { s/.*from *//; s/ *where.*//; /^ *$/d; p;    }**

Comment: You can do as I did and put the two lines into a single file, `sed.script`, and then run `sed -n -f sed.script data.file`.  Or you can write `sed -n -e '…first line…' -e '…second line…' data.file`.  You can probably even put them both into a single `-e` argument, probably with a semicolon separating the two lines, but I don't like unreadable code so I wouldn't do that.

Comment: I am only getting "emp", because the other query sal,.. is having newline between the "from and where"

Comment: Please tell me how to escape the newline and read the next line to

Comment: @BhavishDA: I can't work out what you mean. Please update the question with your extra example to show what problem you're having. Any 'parsing' solution based on regexes is going to be fragile; changes in the SQL to be parsed will find edge cases. If you want to do the job properly, parse the SQL as SQL, not using regexes. You have [two](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29425179) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29425591/) from [mkelement0](http://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) which replace blanks with newlines and then work with the output that may be better for you. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[continuation…]_ However, even those are vulnerable to not understanding nested SQL constructs like the query shown in my answer.  There'd be a FROM, then another FROM, then a WHERE and another WHERE, and you'd probably want to process the inner FROM/WHERE pair to get material and heavily modify the processing in the code handling the outer FROM/WHERE pair.

Comment: Based on the answer to the linked question, it sounds like the `n` isn't actually needed, correct? (If `from` (and `where`) were removed from the pattern space by the first command, the 2nd command will _not_ start a range for that same input line.)

Comment: @mklement0: Well, there's one way to find out whether the first `n` is needed; try it.  And a quick test indicates that it isn't needed — though I'd keep it to get rid of the testing when it is known there's nothing to test.  But it was never that (first) `n` that was causing trouble.

Comment: Yes, the quick test works, but I wanted to confirm that my understanding is correct in general.  Given what http://stackoverflow.com/a/29427611/45375 tells us, I think it would be more helpful to future readers to _remove_ the `n` and add an explanation (or at least a direct link to the explanation), because understanding why it is not needed explains an aspect of `sed`'s behavior that is counter-intuitive (as it was to you). (It would also explain why there _mustn't_ be `n` at the end of the _2nd_ command.)

Answer (score 0):

<sup>The caveat noted in [Jonathan Leffler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29417566/45375) applies: won't work with *nested* SQL statements.</sup>

Here's a pragmatic solution that combines `tr` and `sed`:

With *GNU* Sed:

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' < test.txt | sed -n '/^from$/I,/^where$/I { s///; t; p; }'
```

With *BSD* Sed (also used on OSX; this is a POSIX-compliant solution that will *also* work with GNU Sed) - note that using `I` for case-insensitive matching is, unfortunately, not supported in *BSD* Sed, so the following only matches all-lowercase `from` and `where`:

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' < test.txt | sed -n -e '/^from$/,/^where$/ { s///; t' -e 'p; }'
```

- `tr -s ' ' '\n'` effectively splits the input into individual tokens, each on a separate line.
- The `sed` command then extracts the table names:

  - Note that the only difference between the GNU and the BSD command is that BSD Sed requires a newline after `t`, which in this case is implicitly provided by providing the rest of the script as a separate `-e` option:
  - `/^from$/,/^where$/` matches *ranges* of lines, *including* the `from` and `where` lines.
  - `s///; t` is a trick that skips the `from` and `where` lines, effectively only printing (`p`) what's *between* them:

    - `s///` is a dummy substitution:

      - Not specifying a regex inside `//` implies that the *same regex that matched the current line* is reused.
      - The *result* of the substitution is irrelevant - the only point is to perform *any* substitution, which *will only happen for the endpoints of the range*.
    - `t` then branches - in the absence of a target label name - to the *end* of the script, IF a substitution took place - which will only be the case for the *endpoints* of the range, effectively skipping them.
    - `p` - i.e., printing the current line - is then only performed for the lines *between* the `from` and `where` lines.

*Caveat*: If there are *multiple* whitespace-separated tokens between `from` and `where`, they are each output on a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>The caveat noted in [Jonathan Leffler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29417566/45375) applies: won't work with *nested* SQL statements.</sup>

If you're using *GNU* `grep` (as found on Linux), try the following:

```
tr -s '\n' ' ' < test.txt | grep -Pio '(?<= from ).*?(?= where )'
```

- `tr -s '\n' ' '` replaces runs of newlines with a space each, resulting in a *single* line.

  - (A side effect of this is that if tokens inside a `from`/`where` pair span multiple lines, they are output as a single-line, space-separated list.)
- `grep` command:

  - `-P` activates support for PCREs (Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions), which provide advanced features such as look-ahead and look-behind assertions.
  - `-o` causes Grep to only output the *matching* part(s) of each line, and `i` performs case-insensitive matching.
  - `(?<= from )` uses a *look-behind assertion* to match `from` without including it in the match
  - `(?<= where )` uses a *look-ahead assertion* to match `where` without including it in the match
  - `.*?` *non-greedily* matches *any* sequence of characters; the non-greedy modifier `?` is required to prevent `.*` from matching through the very *last* occurrence of `where` on the input line.

---

*BSD* `grep` (as also used on OSX), doesn't support `-P`, so an extra extraction step is needed to remove the `from` and `where` keyword from the matches, using `awk`:

```
tr -s '\n' ' ' < test.txt | grep -Eio ' from .*? where ' | 
  awk -F ' from | where ' '{ print $2 }'
```

Answer (score -1):

Not pretty, but working (on the same line):

```
grep "from.*where" test.txt | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

For universal solution, I'd use python, because grep doesn't work with multilines.

Comment: still it need to match "dep" and "sal"

Comment: Do you need this values only via shell?

Comment: Promising, but you'd first have to make sure that the input is single-line; next, you'd have to make sure that `grep` only outputs the _matching_ part(s) of the input; finally, you'd have to make sure that `.*where` doesn't greedily match all the way to the very _last_ instance of `where` on the input line.