# Why does an n instead of b or d or nothing change the behaviour of sed in this script?

Tags: sed

While developing an answer for the question [How to extract content between two patterns in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414678/how-to-extract-content-between-two-patterns-in-unix/), I came across a behaviour in `sed` which I can't explain — can you?

Data file: `data`

```
Goodbye

select *   
from dep  
where jkdsfj  

select *   
from sal   
where jkdsfj  

select elephants
from abject poverty
join flying tigers
where abelone = shellfish;

select mouse
from toolset
join animals where tail = cord
and buttons = legs

Hello
```

The objective is to select the text between the words `from` and `where`.

Here are 4 variants of a script:

- `script.16`

  ```
  /from/,/where/ { s/.*from *//; s/ *where.*//; /^ *$/d; p;    }
  ```
- `script.17`

  ```
  # Bust by final n;
  /from/,/where/ { s/.*from *//; s/ *where.*//; /^ *$/d; p; n; }
  ```
- `script.18`

  ```
  /from/,/where/ { s/.*from *//; s/ *where.*//; /^ *$/d; p; d; }
  ```
- `script.19`

  ```
  /from/,/where/ { s/.*from *//; s/ *where.*//; /^ *$/d; p; b
  }
  ```

These all work with both BSD (Mac OS X) `sed` and GNU `sed`.  The last script could use `b; }` and it would work with GNU `sed` but BSD `sed` rejects it.

The trouble is that the output from `script.17` is different from the other 3, and I can't fathom why:

```
$ sed -n -f script.16 data
dep  
sal   
abject poverty
join flying tigers
toolset
join animals
$ sed -n -f script.17 data
dep  
select *   
abject poverty
toolset
and buttons = legs
Hello
$
```

Why is the `select *` and the `and buttons = legs` and `Hello` in the output?

```
$ sed -n -f script.18 data
dep  
sal   
abject poverty
join flying tigers
toolset
join animals
$ sed -n -f script.19 data
dep  
sal   
abject poverty
join flying tigers
toolset
join animals
$
```

Why does the use of `n` change the behaviour of `sed` like this?  From some variations I've tried with diagnostic 'printing', it appears that the `n` prevents `sed` from recognizing when it has seen the `where` properly, but `b` and `d` both jump to the next cycle, rather like `n` does normally, but something is different.

Given that two independent implementations do the same thing, I have to assume it is intentional, but … why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Summary

The issue is with the range and what is in the pattern space when the range is evaluated.

Range endpoints in sed are matched against the contents of the pattern space at the time the range is evaluated, not with respect to the original input lines.  Thus, for `sed -n '/start/,/end/{...}'`, what matters is what is in the pattern space at the beginning of the commands, not what is in the pattern space later after commands have been processed or `n` has caused more lines to be read.

#### Simple Example

The problem with `p;n` in combination with a range can be illustrated with code that is much simpler.  Note that, unlike `b` and `d`, the command `n` reads in a line.  Consequently, `sed -n 'p;n'` prints every other line.  For example:

```
$ seq 5 | sed -n 'p;n'
1
3
5
```

Now, observe `p;n` in combination with a range:

```
$ seq 5 | sed -n '/1/,/3/{p;n;}'
1
3
```

The above works as expected.  The following, however, surprises:

```
$ seq 5 | sed -n '/1/,/2/{p;n;}'
1
3
5
```

The line containing `2` is read in by the `n` command and is then promptly discarded.  The line containing `2` does not appear in the pattern space when the range `/1/,/2/` is evaluated.  Thus, `sed` never sees the end of `/1/,/2/` and it keeps on going thinking it is within the range.

#### Script 17

Now, let's consider your script 17, slightly modified:

```
sed -n '/from/,/where/ { s/.*from */BEGIN/; s/ *where.*/END/; /^ *$/d; p; n; }' data
BEGINdep  
select *   
END
BEGINabject poverty
END
BEGINtoolset
and buttons = legs
Hello
```

Here, we see that the range `/from/,/where/` continues from an appearance of `from` to the next time that `where` appears in the pattern buffer *at the start of the command when the range is evaluated*.  An instance of `where` that is read by `n` never ends a range.

#### A Further Demonstration

Consider the range `/1/,/END/` where `END` nevers appears in the file:

```
$ seq 5 | sed -n 's/3/END/; /1/,/END/{p;n}'
1
END
```

Even though `END` nevers appears in the file, it appears in the pattern space at the time that the range is evaluated.  Thus, it ends the range.

As one more demonstration, let's change the order of the above commands.  Below, we see that `END` does not end the range though it gets printed out:

```
$ seq 5 | sed -n ' /1/,/END/{s/3/END/; p; n}'
1
END
5
```

This is because `END` is not in the pattern space when the range is evaluated.  Thus, `sed` never sees the end to the range.